# How to use Django with Svelte?

Tags: django, templates, svelte

I know it is possible to just copy index.html generated by Svelte and use it as a template, but I have a few questions:

1. Is there a plugin that eases up the process?
2. Where do I put the CSS and bundle.js files?
3. Is it even advisable to use these two together?

Answer (score 3):

You can find an example here: https://github.com/cdrappi/django-svelte

Answer (score 3):

I've put together a package for integrating Svelte and Django: [django-svelte](https://github.com/thismatters/django-svelte)

You still have to be responsible for building the bundle and ensuring that django knows where the bundle can be found. django-svelte provides a templatetag for referencing the bundle and a template for the Svelte environment.